# pop up select list when clicking on text field android

Tags: android, list, view, popup, widget

I want an android widget to have a text field for searching a text. text can be two types(for example: search in topic or search in content text) that when click on text field, a pop-up choosing list appear under it by sliding down effect. when choose one of them, the list slides up and hides. and search will be done according to choosed item in pop-up list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom textview and a [ListPopupWindow](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FListPopupWindow.html&ei=ytf9VKSRItDguQTizYLwAQ&usg=AFQjCNFTkT4a6Ji8pmRrPrREueBWP_MspA&sig2=XSCjLgu-rqXPc6MTaB_Cnw&bvm=bv.87611401,d.c2E) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). This will be a better approach as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this perhaps , 
[image]

This is autoCompleteTextView A pretty good example is available here, Check this out 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: no. I want a popup list with two options for select